# Trying to understand Laplace's equation

Tags: gravity, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

I'm struggling here so please excuse if I'm writing nonsense.

I understand that the gravitational potential field, a scalar field, is given by $$\phi=\frac{-Gm}{r}$$

where $\phi$
  is the gravitational potential energy of a unit mass in a gravitational field $g$
 . The gradient of this is (a vector field)

$$g=-\nabla\phi=-\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\right)$$

And the divergence of this vector field is $$\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi=\nabla^{2}\phi=4\pi G\rho$$
 and is called Poisson's equation. If the point is outside of the mass, then $$\rho=0$$
  and Poisson's equation becomes

$$\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi=0$$

My question is, how do I express $\phi=\frac{-Gm}{r}$
  as a function of $x,y,z$ 
  so I can then end up with $\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi=0$
  in empty space $r\neq 0$? I would have thought that I could write $$\phi=\frac{-Gm}{r}=\frac{-Gm}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}$$
 but when I try to calculate $\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi$
 from this, I don't get zero for $r\neq 0$. I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to compute the Laplacian of

$$
\phi=\frac{-Gm}{r}=\frac{-Gm}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}
$$

This means applying the $\nabla$ operator twice.

Once:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla \phi
&=
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \phi(x, y, z) = \\
%
&= Gm \left( \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} , \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} , \frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \right) = \\
%
&= -g(x, y, z)
\end{aligned}
$$

Twice:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2 \phi &= \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi \\
&= Gm \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} , \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} , \frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \right) = \\
&= Gm \left( \frac{2x^2-y^2-z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}} + \frac{2y^2-x^2-z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}} + \frac{2z^2-x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}} \right) = \\
%
&= 0
\end{aligned}
$$

because the $x$'s, $y$'s and $z$'s on top cancel out. In reality it's nonzero at $(x,y,z) = 0$ because you can't divide by zero.

Comment: Comment to the answer(v1): The [Kronecker delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) should be replaced with the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). The Kronecker delta function is not relevant here.

Comment: @mtrencseni - thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. How/why does Laplacian equal zero when the radius doesn't equal zero. I'm thinking that if I differentiate phi twice wrt r I should be getting zero. Is that correct? How does that give zero? I'm a physics novice so don't worry about making your answer too simple.

Comment: Added a more explicit calculation for you.

Comment: @mtrencseni - Now I think I get it. I was making assumptions that I shouldn't (I was assuming I could ignore y and z and find the Laplacian of -Gm/x). I popped the real phi into the WolframAlpha calculator took second partial derivatives, added them all up and there was zero. Brilliant. Thank you very much.